# Win 32 API, drawing two child windows with vertical splitter bar

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

Below is code, which I am using for creating child windows:

case WM_CREATE:
    hInst = ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam) -> hInstance;

```
hWnd1 = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_LEFT,
            "edit", NULL,  
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 
            hWnd, (HMENU) 1,
            hInst, NULL );

hWnd2 = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_LEFT,
            "edit", NULL,  
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 
            hWnd, (HMENU) 2,
            hInst, NULL );
```

But this code produces horizontal splitter, and I want vertical splitter.
First I thought, if I change height and width parameters, I could create vertical splitter. But it was of no use.

For full code and sample example (in order to save space on SO):
http://old.sumitbirla.com/software/src/splitter.c

So, what is exactly keyword/parameter, which would produce vertical splitter bar.

Comment: This would seem to create two edit controls both with zero size. In what way is that a horizontal splitter?

Comment: You might want to consider reading about this newfangled [UNICODE](http://unicode.org/) stuff. And [use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx).

Comment: Jonathan : First I thought CreateWindow and CreateWindowEx differs in terms of UNICODE (which is totally wrong, after re-reading msdn doc).
Thanks IInspectable: For giving MSDN link of UNICODE. 
What I want to do is - A main window, with two child windows, one of is left navigation pane, and other on right is text editor. 
And for vertical splitter, do I have to add third child window in between with very small width, or only two can suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted just creates two child windows. It has nothing to do with vertical or horizontal splitter. Handle the WM_SIZE message in the parent window to position and size the child windows for a vertical or horizontal split.